# Arithmetic operations on Myanmar digits

Tags: java, android, localization

User enters Myanmar digit (with special soft keyboard).
Then, I need to increment that digit. But when I parseInt the input, digitOne becomes Arabic. Is there any way to keep it Myanmar?

```
String digitText= editText.getText().toString();
Integer digitOne = Integer.parseInt(digitText);
```

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/examples/ThaiDigits.java)'s an Oracle sample for dealing with Taïwanese digits, I expect you'd need the same for Myanmar except with a `Locale("my", "MM")` locale. Calling that Locale's `.getScript()` method should return `Mymr` if everything goes right (which it doesn't on my system)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I could find was to simply transliterate it after arithmetic operation:

```
public static String getMyanmarDigitsText(@NonNull String numericStr) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numericStr.length(); j++) {
        String character = numericStr.substring(j, j + 1);
        String replacement = MyUtils.getMyanmarDigitSymbol(character);

        if (replacement != null) numericStr = numericStr.replace(character, replacement);
    }

    return numericStr;
}

public static String getEnglishDigitsText(@NonNull String numericStr) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numericStr.length(); j++) {
        String character = numericStr.substring(j, j + 1);
        String replacement = MyUtils.getEnglishDigitSymbol(character);

        if (replacement != null) numericStr = numericStr.replace(character, replacement);
    }

    return numericStr;
}

@Nullable
private static String getMyanmarDigitSymbol(String digit) {
    switch (digit) {
        case "0":
            return "၀";
        case "1":
            return "၁";
        case "2":
            return "၂";
        case "3":
            return "၃";
        case "4":
            return "၄";
        case "5":
            return "၅";
        case "6":
            return "၆";
        case "7":
            return "၇";
        case "8":
            return "၈";
        case "9":
            return "၉";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Nullable
public static String getEnglishDigitSymbol(String digit) {
    switch (digit) {
        case "၀":
            return "0";
        case "၁":
            return "1";
        case "၂":
            return "2";
        case "၃":
            return "3";
        case "၄":
            return "4";
        case "၅":
            return "5";
        case "၆":
            return "6";
        case "၇":
            return "7";
        case "၈":
            return "8";
        case "၉":
            return "9";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

public static boolean isMyanmarDigits(String numericStr) {
    return numericStr.contains("၀")
            || numericStr.contains("၁")
            || numericStr.contains("၂")
            || numericStr.contains("၃")
            || numericStr.contains("၄")
            || numericStr.contains("၅")
            || numericStr.contains("၆")
            || numericStr.contains("၇")
            || numericStr.contains("၈")
            || numericStr.contains("၉");
}

public static boolean isEnglishDigits(String numericStr) {
    return numericStr.contains("0")
            || numericStr.contains("1")
            || numericStr.contains("2")
            || numericStr.contains("3")
            || numericStr.contains("4")
            || numericStr.contains("5")
            || numericStr.contains("6")
            || numericStr.contains("7")
            || numericStr.contains("8")
            || numericStr.contains("9");
}f
```